# Update a Donut Chart Arc Based on a Brush Extent

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

[image]

I'm [using a D3 brush to update the arcs of a donut chart](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/10054222), but the update is occurring only after I release the brush. I know that D3 is capable of brush-based continuous updating as Mike has done [in this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367); what part of that code have I missed in my adaptation?

Here's the function that I currently use to do the updating:

```
function brushended() {
  path.select('.donutPath')
    .data(pie([brush.extent()[1],100 - brush.extent()[1]]))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you need to listen to is `.on("brush",...`, like:

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .extent([0,40])
    .on("brush", brushended);
```

You should change the name of the function to better reflect the situation, but this alone will make it work.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LsTLt/1/) with the listener changes, but also with changes to the way the update selection was being handled.

Comment: That did it! Regarding the function changes, do you have any suggestions about how I can get rid of the replicate pie slices that show up when I move the brush now [in the updated version](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/10054222)?

Comment: @BillMorris That is because of the way you are handling the selection on brush update. I have created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LsTLt/) for you with the fixes.

Comment: Thank you! I'm finally getting a handle on the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)